# Laravel 4 Sessions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Can I enable more than one driver for storage. For example could I enable native driver which is already enabled and also have cookies enabled. I'm creating a package that I want to give that option.

Answer (score 0):

u could do this by change the config at the runtime . use `Config` class : 
`Config::set('session.driver','cookies')` .
 but please notic that : 
  Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests. 
hope this will help u ! good luck ! O(∩_∩)O